# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in Python using moviepy

Tags: python-3.x, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, moviepy

I always get the error bellow while I run my script on Windows 10, but when I use my WSL it works perfectly.

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1351, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 418, in __enter__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 311, in acquire
  RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

This is my python code:

```
import moviepy.editor

   
# loading video dsa gfg intro video 
clip = VideoFileClip("shprt.mp4") 
   
# getting only first 5 seconds 
clip = clip.subclip(0, 5) 
  
# previewing the clip at fps = 20 
clip.preview(fps = 30)
```

When I use it

Comment: I have tried: sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)